# Why are some <hr> in HTML not going 0px in height?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to get the height of the hr to 0px, any other amount seems to be fine and the two matches. I will also post my code at the bottom. I am not sure if this is a CSS issue or an HTML issue. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Here are two of my hr elements with the CSS code I made with it, yet both look different

[image: hr with 0 height]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Personal Website</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: #97BFB4;
        }

        hr {
            background-color: whitesmoke;
            border-style: dotted;
            height : 0px;
            width: 10%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table cellspacing= "20">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><img src=""></td>

                <td>
                    <h1> <a href="">Personal
                        Site </a></h1>
                    <p><em> Computer Engineer at Stony Brook University </em></p>
                
                    <p>
                        
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <h3><a href="">Experience</a></h3>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>
                Dates
            </th>
            <th>
                Work
            </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>June 2021</td>
                <td>Undergraduate Researcher</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sept 2020</td>
                <td>Vice President Of Robotics</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
       <tfoot></tfoot>
        
    </table>
    
    <hr>
</body>
```

Before Update:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Personal Website</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: #97BFB4;
        }

        hr {
            background-color: whitesmoke;
            border-style: dotted;
            border-width: 2px 0 0 0;
            height : 0px;
            width: 10%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table cellspacing= "20">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><img src=""></td>

                <td>
                    <h1> <a href="">Personal
                        Site </a></h1>
                    <p><em> Computer Engineer at Stony Brook University </em></p>

                    <p>

                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <h3><a href="">Experience</a></h3>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>
                Dates
            </th>
            <th>
                Work
            </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>June 2021</td>
                <td>Undergraduate Researcher</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sept 2020</td>
                <td>Vice President Of Robotics</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
       <tfoot></tfoot>

    </table>

    <hr>
</body>
```

**UPDATE:**
I did find a way to get to my goal by deleting the border color and changing the border style for the different sides of the border to none except for one. I got the dotted line I was looking for, but I still would like to understand why exactly my issue came about in the first place? It didn't seem there was any real distinction between the way I set up my first `<hr>` tag and my second. If someone can clear that up in case the issue occurs with other tags that would be greatly appreciated. Also, I will put code snippets of before and after.

After Update:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Personal Website</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: #97BFB4;
        }

        hr {
            /* background-color: whitesmoke; */
            border-style: dotted none none none;
            border-color: grey;
            border-width: 5px;
            height : 0px;
            width: 10%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table cellspacing= "20">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><img src=""></td>

                <td>
                    <h1> <a href="">Personal
                        Site </a></h1>
                    <p><em> Computer Engineer at Stony Brook University </em></p>

                    <p>

                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <h3><a href="">Experience</a></h3>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>
                Dates
            </th>
            <th>
                Work
            </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>June 2021</td>
                <td>Undergraduate Researcher</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sept 2020</td>
                <td>Vice President Of Robotics</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
       <tfoot></tfoot>

    </table>

    <hr>
</body>
```

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish ? Clearly "0 pixel height" doesn't *really* exist (plus i do not think the value `0` can even understand units in CSS). If you wanted to hide it you could use `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`. If you just wanted the *tiny*est size then maybe you want 0.0001rem or something like that. Technically there is a difference between what CSS calls a *pixel*, and what an actual physical pixel on your screen truely is, but that's generally not important for webdesigners.

Comment: @Raxi Well my goal here was to eventually have a dotted line, and I tried having a 0px height to achieve this. If a 0px didn't truly exist, that's ok but I am more concerned with why one hr tag truly gets to nearly 0px while the other will not. The reason this is my concern is that I don't know if I should expect different behaviors from these two tags for other properties as well.

Comment: Sounds to me like you don't want the `hr` to be visible at all, you just want to be able to draw a border ? You could use any other blocklevel element for that (such as a `<div>`), which is already invisible in and of itself (unless you give it a background or put some content in there). And for height i'd recommend just going with `1px`. `0px` itself is impossible it'd likely just end up appearing as an unreliable `1px` item under different conditions.

Comment: @Raxi I appreciate the advice, I'll try some of the workarounds. However, I will leave my question as my main concern are tags that have the same name yet different behaviors. Even if I find a way around this issue, if another problem similar to this arises with either the hr tag or anything else then I would like to get a better understanding. I will update my question when I am done with my workaround to be more focused on the "why" aspect.

Comment: It's not really different behaviour. It's behaviour that happens all over webpages whenever the numbers don't line up exactly. How do you render a 99px image at width:100px ?; How many pixels wide is a `width: 33.3%;`-div in a `100px`-container. The answer will involve rounding numbers causing them to go a little bit up, or a little bit down. You're seeing the same effect here with the border aligning differently under high pressure. If your content was a `100px` by `100px` block then you wouldn't be able to tell the border difference.

Comment: In the top example it ended up being a 3 pixel affair, and in the lower example a 2 pixel affair. I'm guessing its 2 times 1px for the border, and then either 0px or 1px for the content that is in between the borders (due to rounding up or down).

Comment: If I had continued to make hr tags under these high-pressure conditions, should I expect more variations? i.e. if I added more hr tags with height 0, would they randomly be between [0,1] pixels?

Comment: No i suspect not. In your case it either rounds up or down, there's not really another outcome. Things end up being rounded to *an integer of whatever the smallest supported (sub)unit is* (1 pixel in this case i suppose). It's possible that, when on top of the height being such a dodgy edge-case (where rounding can make or break it), the `width` also being an edge case (such as in a `width: 0.5px; height: 0.5px;`-type of situation), then you might potentially have a handful of different possible endresults i suppose

Comment: @Raxi Oh ok, can you post your answer so that I can claim the problem solved?

Comment: For any designer though, you either want to be clear as to what you want (eg: supply whole numbers, not partial pixels), or you want to have conditions in place where either result is fine. If your website has a content area which contains lots of paragraphs of text, which is `width: 1207.5px`; then it'll look fine no matter if it ends up being 1207 or 1208px, noone will be able to tell.

Comment: Sure i'll group the comments together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really different behaviour.

It's behaviour that happens all over webpages whenever the numbers don't line up exactly.

- How do you render a 99px image at `width: 100px;` ?
- How many pixels wide is a `width: 33.3%;`-div in a `100px`-container ?

The answer will involve rounding numbers causing them to go a little bit up, or a little bit down. You're seeing the same effect here with the border aligning differently under high pressure.

If instead of your `<hr>`, it was a roughly `100px` by `100px` block, then you wouldn't be able to tell when the border was slightly different in different cases.

In your case, in the top example, your bordered `<hr>` ended up being displayed as a *3 pixel high* component, and in the lower example as *2 pixels*. I'm guessing that consists of:

- `1px` for the border-top
- `1px` for the border-bottom
- either 0px or 1px for the content that is in between the borders (due to rounding up or down).

---

> If I had continued to make hr tags under these high-pressure
> conditions, should I expect more variations? i.e. if I added more hr
> tags with height 0, would they randomly be between [0,1] pixels?
>
> Saad Satter

No i suspect not. In your case it either rounds up or down, there's not really another outcome.

Things end up being rounded to an integer of whatever the smallest supported (sub)unit is (1 pixel in this case i suppose).

It is possible that, if on top of the height being such a dodgy edge-case (where rounding can make or break it), the width was **also** such an edge case, then you might potentially have a handful of different possible endresults. A `width: 0.5px; height: 0.5px;`-type of situation.

---

For any designer though, you either want to be clear as to what you want (eg: supply whole numbers, not partial pixels), or you want to have conditions in place where either result is fine.

If your website has a content area which contains lots of paragraphs of text, which is `width: 1207.5px;` then it'll look fine no matter if it ends up being `1207px` or `1208px`, no-one will be able to tell.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, we know that 0 means nothing. When the value is empty then we use 0. Now, here you are saying in CSS that make the height of hr 0px. That means no value. So, without a single px it can't show anything to you in display. That's why 0px doesn't exist. Hope you got it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In theory what you are doing is fine, there is theoretically no problem with having a zero height element with borders.

However, CSS pixels do not on many modern screens, map one to one with screen pixels. Several screen pixels may be used for one CSS pixel.

There can therefore be edge effects when the system has to decide exactly where to place things. You can see this sometimes by zooming. In your example try this and you will probably see the unwanted white line come and go at different magnifications.

So in answer to one of your queries, yes it is something to avoid. In your case try setting just the top border at twice the height without the other borders and see what happens.

Comment: Although Raxi is more descriptive I like this answer a lot too, it's easier to understand. Thank you!!